# The electron potential energy of a single electron (in $H^+_2$ ) at any point

Tags: electromagnetism, potential-energy

In my book it says:

> We can choose a convenient reference by noting that the coulomb force at infinite distance is zero. It makes sense for this case, then, to choose $r=\inf$ as the vacuum level $E_v$:
> $E_p(r=\inf)=E_v$
> (In here, p means potential)

> When the nuclei are allowed to approach each other, an electron would be influenced by both nuclei according to Coulomb's law. The electron potential energy of a single electron (in $H^+_2$ ) at any point is now

> $E_p=E_v-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_1}-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_2} $

> where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the distances between the electron and each of the two nuclei, respectively.

But i can't understand. As i know, the potential energy's formula is $E_p=\int_C\vec{F}\bullet\vec{dr}$

And, by superposition, we can get $E_p=E_1+E_2=\int_C(\vec{F}_1+\vec{F}_2)\bullet\vec{dr}$

where $\vec{F_1}$ and $E_1$ are force and potential energy due to one charge. And $\vec{F_2}$,$E_2$ are due to other charge.

So i think, $E_1=E_v-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_1} $,$E_2=E_v-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_2} $

Thus, it think $E_p=2E_v-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_1}-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_2} $, not $E_p=E_v-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_1}-\frac{q^2}{(4\pi\epsilon_0)r^2_2} $

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In your energy formulas, you meant to write $1/r$, not $1/r^2$, right?

Comment: This would be clearer if you used the standard $T$ ($V$) for kinetic (potential) energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) First, you can add any constant you want to the energy without changing the physics, so even if you decide to add $E_v$ to each of $E_1$ and $E_2$ so that $E_p=E_1+E_2=2E_v+\cdots$, you could always decide to subtract $E_v$ from $E_p$ to get the expression in the book. So in that sense, there is not really a right answer to this question.

(b) If you want to interpret what the book is saying physically, then the correct energy superposition you should do is with **three** sources, not two:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\rm Potential\ Energy} &=& {\rm Energy\ of\ Charge\ 1} + {\rm Energy\ of\ Charge\ 2} + {\rm Vacuum\ Energy} \\
E_p &=& E_1 + E_2 + E_v \\
&=& -\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r_1}-\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r_2} + E_v
\end{eqnarray}